How to proper setup Spark on Databricks and DLT pipeline?
I have a DLT pipeline in Databricks from the Azure portal. I would like to increase the maximum size of a streaming message, which is 10 MB by default.
Could someone show me how to properly configure pipeline and what is configuration parameter? I need to double the maximum size of a streaming message.
I noticed that one of possible parameters could be the Spark variable "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold". I tried adding this configuration to the top of my notebook as well as in a pipeline job cluster controlled via a Json file.

you can try to set this configuration directly when you are creating your dlt pipeline, you can there fine tune the cluster configuration, in the advanced option.

fetch.message.max.bytes - this will determine the largest size of a message that can be fetched by the consumer.

This is what I did (adding parameter to Json file). Doesn't work.

i updated the response, i did not understand the question at first glence, you can try spark.config.set(fetch.message.max.bytes, 15728640 ) to get 15MB message size.

It has no impact at the end. The limit does not changed.

I finally figured this out. You are fully right. But the issue was with the version of DLT. Only preview version allows to set up this parameter. I don't know why DLT for current version does not see this variable.
